# Flickr API: Cross domain not allowed from JS but allowed from Fiddler

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to use Flickr API to retrieve photos: https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/

If I use it from Javascript:

```
function flImageRequest(keyword){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

I get error:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access"

I understand it's a security error but when I make request from Fiddler via composer - it returns XML response just fine.

What's going on? is that a browser issue? Can I somehow supress browser security?

Comment: The answer is no. Plenty of info on the internet about Same Origin Policy and CORS

Comment: So without even a local server -its not doable?